# R: detecting sequences

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of numbers, that has some numbers that are in sequence and some that aren't:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,11,14,16,17)
```

How would I manipulate this so that a string is returned such that the sequences are grouped together?

```
y <- "1-3, 5-8, 11, 14, 16-17"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We create a grouping variable ('gr') by comparing the adjacent elements using `diff`, check for the output that are not 1, do the `cumsum`.  We use this in `tapply` to `paste` the `range` of elements in 'x'.

```
gr <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(x)!=1))
y <- unname(tapply(x, gr, FUN= function(.x)
                  paste(unique(range(.x)), collapse='-')))
```

If we need a single string, `paste` the 'y' together using `toString` which is a wrapper for `paste(..., collapse=', ')`

```
y <- toString(y)
y
#[1] "1-3, 5-8, 11, 14, 16-17"
```

---

We can also do this using any of the aggregate by group methods.  For example, using `data.table`, we convert 'x' to 'data.table', grouped by 'gr' (created using `cumsum(...)`), we `paste` the elements together, and use `toString` as before.

```
library(data.table)
y1 <- setDT(list(x))[,paste(unique(range(V1)), collapse='-') ,
                 by = .(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(V1)!=1)))]$V1
toString(y1)
#[1] "1-3, 5-8, 11, 14, 16-17"
```